# How to cycle/repeat a baked animation?

Tags: animation, loop

I downloaded a short looped animation (15 frames) of a horse. It was an .abc-file.
Now i want to extend the anmiation (looping it for 300 frames) but i don´t know how.
The mesh has no animation data, no actions, no keyframes, nothing..

Is there a workaround for that?

Comment: Maybe copy the keyframes and paste them along the timeline?

Comment: there are no keyframes!

Comment: Hello, please share your file because it is hard to guess how it is animated

Comment: how to share a file here?

Comment: it´s this file: https://sketchfab.com/3d-models/horse-run-cycle-on-place-8451f03cb1564436bfaa3964dd619a86

Comment: I haven't subscribed to this site, if it's copyright free you can share it